# LuckPerms API permission change not applied

Tags: api, kotlin, plugins, permissions, minecraft

I'm developing a plugin for SpigotMC and try to set a permission in LuckPerms. I use the LuckPerms API for doing that:

```kotlin
val api = LuckPermsProvider.get()
val user = api.getPlayerAdapter(Player::class.java).getUser(event.player)
user.data().add(PermissionNode.builder("my.permission").build())
```

So I have the permission until I reload or restart and I don't see the permission in LuckPerms. It looks like I have to apply the changes somehow.

How can I give a permission to a player?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from the docs, you need to save your changes in order to take effect.(https://luckperms.net/wiki/Developer-API-Usage#saving-changes)

Call `luckPerms.getUserManager().saveUser(user);` after adding the permission (I haven't worked with Kotlin much, so I'm leaving the Java version here.)